# Ruby EBNF COMPSTMT iteration misunderstanding

Tags: ruby, iteration, grammar, bnf

Here is a basic Ruby program:

```rb
puts 1
puts 1
puts 1
puts 1
puts 1
puts 1
puts 1
```

Here are the top rules of the BNF syntax for Ruby (shortened):
source: https://github.com/goruby/goruby/blob/master/goruby.bnf or [https://cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf](https://cse.buffalo.edu/%7Eregan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf)

```
PROGRAM         : COMPSTMT ;

COMPSTMT        : STMT
                | COMPSTMT TERM
                | COMPSTMT TERM EXPR
                | COMPSTMT TERM EXPR TERM ;

STMT            : "BEGIN" "{" COMPSTMT "}"
                | "END" "{" COMPSTMT "}"
                | EXPR ;
```

Since a PROGRAM is only one COMPSTMT, and a COMPSTMT is never just a {COMPSTMT}
, how is this possible for the interpreter to validate my code ? I can't draw the grammar graph leading to my program.

It should only authorize two expressions, no more (COMPSTMT TERM EXPR TERM).

Does Ruby put a begin/end under the hood to authorize an iteration of COMPSTMT, or am I misunderstanding the rules ?

Comment: It sounds like the rarely used [`BEGIN` and `END`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-BEGIN+and+END) feature is the source of your confusion?

Comment: Even though you have gotten an answer pointing out that this is *not* the case in this particular instance, I would like to point out that the most likely explanation for "why does this random stuff I found on the Internet not make sense" is that the random stuff you found on the Internet is plain simply *wrong*.

Answer (score 1):

Do note that the two BNF you shared differ in some parts. I am going to use the definition from the [first source](https://github.com/goruby/goruby/blob/master/goruby.bnf). Also note this is not an official source, this is from the Go language implementation of Ruby, but assume it's correct enough.

First of all we can consider the "puts 1" line as an `EXPR` as it's a command ([see here](https://github.com/goruby/goruby/blob/master/goruby.bnf#L157)), so this is what we need to have at the end. However you are right, you cannot get to 7 `EXPR` values after each other. However that's actually correct, and your issue is that you forgot to add the definition of a `TERM` value. Let's see what it does:

```
TERM            : ";"
                | "\n" ;
```

From this you can easily see that `TERM` actually means **termination** (instead of **term**, a commonly used term (pun intended) in BNF graphs usually occuring when describing the mathematical operation parts of the grammar)

From this it becomes obivous that your code above is not actually 7 `EXPR` values, it is `EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR`, and this we can actually get from the BNF above

Each line is a single substition, except at the very end:

```
PROGRAM
COMPSTMT
COMPSTMT TERM EXPR
COMPSTMT TERM EXPR TERM EXPR
COMPSTMT TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR
COMPSTMT TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR
COMPSTMT TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR
COMPSTMT TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR
STMT TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR
EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR TERM EXPR
EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR "\n" EXPR
"puts 1" "\n" "puts 1" "\n" "puts 1" "\n" "puts 1" "\n" "puts 1" "\n" "puts 1" "\n" "puts 1"
```